# Mobile Service with C# backend: return Guid

Tags: c#, azure

I have just started with Azure 'mobile services', I am using C# as backednd. I am trying to return `Guid` back to the client but I am getting the error: "`Cannot convert source type int to target type Guid`".

Here is my code:

**Model:**

```
public class MobileRegistration : EntityData
    {
        public Guid MobileRegistrationId { get; set; }

    }
```

**Controller:**

```
    public async Task<Guid> GetMobileRegistrationId()
            {
                using (var context = new CustomeeMobileServiceContext())
                {                    
                    var db = context.Database;

                    var model = new MobileRegistration();    

                    // The error is here (I need to get Guid from the SP):
                    //Error: Cannot convert source type int to target type Guid           
                    model.MobileRegistrationId = await db.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("EXEC dbo.MobileRegistration.GetMobileRegistrationId"); 

                    return model.MobileRegistrationId;
                }
            }
```

**Stored Procedure:**

```
Create PROCEDURE GetMobileRegistrationId    
AS

DECLARE @MobileRegistrationID uniqueidentifier
    set @MobileRegistrationID  = NEWID() 

INSERT      
    INTO MobileRegistration (MobileRegistrationID)
VALUES     (@MobileRegistrationID)

select  @MobileRegistrationID as MobileRegistrationID
```

Comment: And you do not even bother telling us where.... you get the error. Amazing. Have some crystal ball? Do NOT dump us a lot of code and then assume it is our job to do your job.

Comment: Dont be mad... I will add it.

Comment: Rather isolate the error and throw away the rest that is not needed. According toe FAQ you have to provide the smallest amount of code necessary to repro the issue.

Comment: Hahaha funny comments.

Answer (score 0):

Consider reading documentation.

> ExecuteSqlCommandAsync

does not return the selected value in the SP as return value. It returns an error code - of the SP. Which you never set. And which is an int.

You need to open a data reader or use a scalar version of execute (which returns row 1 column 1) to get the GUID.

The documentation is obviously clear on that:

> Return Value Type: System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Int32> A task that
>   represents the asynchronous operation. The task result contains the
>   result returned by the database after executing the command.

which indicates you never read it.

Comment: true, I never read it, it was just a sample for what I am trying to achive, I was hoping  some one could suggest a  different context.command that can operate this...as I said this is new to me. anyway you had a bad attitude!

Comment: I agree. I have a terrible attitude. I expect a programmer to read documentation. I expect food in a restaurant to be professionally made. I am disgusted by people working for money in programming never bothering to read documentation. You are right. Terrible.

Comment: It's amaizing how you know my entire story, I am taking money for programming... the real story is that I need to give today an API to another programmer who is working on my startup and as I said this is new to me. You know, sometimes you need to be flexible and fast that's why I asked for help. but you... you can keep read documentation.